# How to create Android ViewPager swipe overshoot/bounce animation?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation

How can I create an animation similar to the stock android launcher animation applied to apps when you change homescreen pages.

Here's a gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh7qE.gif

As the page swipes, the icons slightly overshoot their mark, and settle back to the center. I don't see how I can do that with a PageTransformer and I can't find any resources to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once created a one-time bounce animation:

```
val pixels = binding.pager.width / 8
ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, pixels).apply {
    duration = 200L
    interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
    repeatCount = 3
    repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
    addUpdateListener {
        binding.pager.scrollX = it.animatedValue as Int
    }
}.start()
```

Use `ofInt(0, pixels)` for bouncing left or `ofInt(0, -pixels)`  to bouncing right.

In my code I used a dragging distance of 1/8 of the view pager.
Feel free to choose how much you want to bounce:
`val pixels = PIXELS_TO_DRAG`

Finally, the `repeatCount` determines how many bounces - use 3 for 2 bounces, 5 for 3 bounces, 7 for 4 bounces etc.

You can fire this animation each time a pager transition end and tweak the parameters to get the desired behavior.

Enjoy,
Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

According to @Shlomi, you can do this implementation:

```
        var currentPage = 0

        binding.viewPager.onPageChangeListener {
            val pixels = binding.vpBennefits.width / 8
            ValueAnimator.ofInt(
                0, if (currentPage < it)
                    pixels
                else
                    -pixels
            ).apply {
                duration = 200L
                interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
                repeatCount = 1
                repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
                addUpdateListener {
                    binding.vpBennefits.scrollX = it.animatedValue as Int
                }
            }.start()

            currentPage = it
        }
```

By this way you can obtain the desired effect in both sides